# unable to pass the variable value,how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see my script below.

i need to pass the value of **selectedLang** to a page. but it always shows 0 instead of the updated value. did i miss anything? please advice me.

if i add the BLOCK 2,  inside of BLOCK 1 its working. but the problem is it will not work if i didn't click anyone of the radio button.

```
<script>
var selectedLang = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.slang').click(function()
{
            /*************BLOCk 1 ******************/ 
    var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='lang']:checked");
    if (selected.length > 0) 
    {
        selectedLang = selected.val();
    }
    alert(selectedLang);
            /************** BLOCK 1***************/
});

    /************** BLOCK 2***************/
var options = {
    script:base_url+"?ajax&json=true&limit=6&songauto=true&lang="+selectedLang+"&",
    varname:"input",
    json:true,
    shownoresults:false,
    maxresults:6,
    callback: function (obj) { document.getElementById('testid').value=obj.id; }
};
var as_json = new bsn.AutoSuggest('songsearch', options);
    /*******************************/
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: You're setting `options` and `as_json` when the document loads and `selectedLang` is 0, they will never be updated when `selectedLang` is changed

Comment: Could you please share the html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<script>
    var selectedLang = 0;
    var options;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slang').click(function() {
            var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='lang']:checked");
            if (selected.length) {
                selectedLang = selected.val();
                options.script = base_url+"?ajax&json=true&limit=6&songauto=true&lang="+selectedLang+"&";
            }
        });

        var options = {
            script:base_url+"?ajax&json=true&limit=6&songauto=true&lang="+selectedLang+"&",
            varname:"input",
            json:true,
            shownoresults:false,
            maxresults:6,
            callback: function (obj) { document.getElementById('testid').value=obj.id; }
        };

        var as_json = new bsn.AutoSuggest('songsearch', options);
    }); 
</script>
```

This may work. You might need to manually update `as_json` too. Although you should really think about re-engineering your solution. Basically you just want to make sure every reference to `selectedLang` is updated when it is.

Answer (score 0):

With this setup, it would be always 0, as options object is created before click handler is executed.
You'll have to update the options object from the click handler after you update the 'selectedLang' variable, something like this:

```
selectedLang = selected.val();
options.script = base_url+"?ajax&json=true&limit=6&songauto=true&lang="+selectedLang+"&";
```

and it should work then.